# Get only digits from input and call that number Android

Tags: java, android, numbers

Okay, I am creating an android app, I do like to get the number from an input here `mostLikelyThingHeard` unfortenately my code doesn't work for some reason.

For example when the user says: bel 0612345678

The dialer has to call 0612345678

```
String one = "bel";
if (mostLikelyThingHeard.contains(one)) {
    String numbers = mostLikelyThingHeard.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
    Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + numbers));
    tts.speak(numbers + " wordt gebeld.",
    TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    found = true;
}
```

I also added the right permissions in AndroidManifest.xml, I guess the code is wrong.

Comment: Do you get any error/Exception?

Comment: And issue is in getting number from input or calling?

Comment: Getting number from input, I previously used to split the input and get the last splitted characters. That didn't work so I tried this code.

Comment: Means @user2683292 you want only numeric value from String. Am I right?

Comment: @AndroEmbedded Yeah!

Comment: You are missing call to startActivity. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get numbers from String like this:

```
String numbers = mostLikelyThingHeard.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
```

To call that number, you can use ACTION_CALL. ACTION_DIAL will just open a dialer screen with that number. Also, you have initialized intent, but **you are missing call to `startActivity(intent)`**

```
Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + numbers));
startActivity(call);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah clear helpful answer! :D but @MagicalPhoenixϡ so all characters will be removed then? So for example a6b7 will become 67?

Comment: Yeah. I tried with `String numbers = ("abc 9ddd935345").replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");` and it just keeps numbers :) @user2683292

Comment: What's the difference with "[^0-9]" and [^\\d] o.0?

Comment: Sorry... bit weak in regex.. time to leave office.. happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
Intent.ACTION_CALL
```

and make sure that you are using this before application tag in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex and delete non-digits.

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one..**

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + yours_numbers_values));
   startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess startActivity will trigger the dialer properly.

Comment: and also you may use several Call apps options.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String one = "bel";
String mostLikelyThingHeard="bel 0612345678";
if (mostLikelyThingHeard.contains(one)) {
    String numbers = mostLikelyThingHeard.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+Uri.encode(numbers.trim())));
    startActivity(callIntent);
    tts.speak(numbers + " wordt gebeld.",
    TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    found = true;
}
```

And in Manifest add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" ></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Will try, what does trim do? EDIT: It removes spaces thanks :)